# Response returned from my Spring Boot Rest API is not same as the backend API provided to my rest API

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

In our Spring Boot application, we are calling an third party rest API, which will return us the response data in below format:

Below response will get when data found:

```
  {
    "items": [
        {
            "eventType": "ABC",
            "timestamp": "01-01-2020"
        },
        {
            "eventType": "XYZ",
            "timestamp": "02-02-2020"
        }
    ]
}
```

Below response will get when no data found or empty:

```
  {
    "items": []
}
```

Actually, our rest api will return correct format data when it is success (data found). But when there is no data found (empty data), our rest api is returning  ***like this " {} " instead of " {'items':[]} "*** which is not correct.

In controller, we calling the service class methods:

```
    @Autowired
    private ProductService productService;

    @GetMapping("/getProduct/{productNo}")
    public ResponseEntity<Product> getProduct(@PathVariable("productNo") String productNo) {
        logger.debug("--- getProduct() Method Called ---");
        return ResponseEntity.ok(productService.getProduct(productNo));
    }
```

In service class, we calling the backend url using:

```
    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Override
    public Product getProduct(String productNo) {
        return restTemplate.getForObject("BACK_END_URL/" + productNo, Product.class);
    }
```

Please let us know whether we are missing anything here or done anything wrong.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Hi Jay, Can you show me the Product class ? @Jay

Comment: Our Third Party application is returning us the below response:
`{
    "items": []
}`
But after we received it then we are putting into the respective object and returning back the response to calling api. Below is the response which we are receiving which is wrong:
`{}`

Comment: But you have to properly setup the Product class. Can you show it.

Comment: @CodeWalter,   please find the Product class  : public class Product {
    private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();

    public Product() {
    }

    public List<Item> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(List<Item> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }
}

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get `[]` when your `items` is empty, initialize `items` list and change `items` setter in the `Product` class like below:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Product {

    private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();

    public Product() {
    }

    public List<Item> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(List<Item> items) {
        if (items != null) {
            this.items = items;
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

```
{
    "items": []
}
```

Comment: Add this line of code `private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();` instead of `private List<Item> items;`  in your `Product` class and test again.

Comment: Thanks @Nasir, but we not creating any response. The way you mentioned is know to us. But we want to know, how to pass the empty response which is coming from third party side. In Service class, we are calling the third party url like below: public Product getProduct(String productNo) { Product prod = restTemplate.getForObject("BACK_END_URL/" + productNo, Product.class); return prod; } The empty response will get, when we call the "restTemplate.getForObject()" then put into the respective object and returning it.

Comment: Can you put your `Product` class in the question?

Comment: please find the Product class  : public class Product {
    private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();

    public Product() {
    }

    public List<Item> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(List<Item> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }
}

Comment: @Jay, I changed my answer and changed the `items` setter and added an `if` to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this product class

```
public class Product {
     private List<Item> items;

     public Product() {
     }

     public Product(List<Item> items) {
       super();
       this.items = items;
    }



    public List<Item> getItems() {
       return items;
    }

    public void setItems(List<Item> items) {
       this.items = items;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @CodeWalter, I changed the Product class as you mentioned, but still same problem and we are still getting " {} " instead of " {'items':[]} " :(

Comment: You should debug inside the getForObject() method to get exact reason.